# JadeJS: Value of input not set when using for-loops

Tags: for-loop, input, web, pug

I'm currently playing around with Jade right now to see how it works.

Here I have a for-loop to create inputs for me.

```
-for ( var i = 0; i < numItems; i++ ) 
   -for each in ['name', 'cost', 'amount']
      input(id=each,type=itemsVar[each]['type'],placeholder=itemsVar[each]['val'],name=each, value=each+i)
```

This is the output

[image]

Why is it that only the name inputs have values but not the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value and input types are different. The value type for all of those inputs is a string, and the type for cost and amount is number.

An alphabet string cannot be a number, hence why it doesn't show.